# Youtube videos keeps buffering

Tags: 20.04, youtube

I download Ubuntu 20.04 on Oracle virtualbox 6.1.8  and YouTube videos keep buffering browser independent tried both Mozilla and chrome. Any idea how i can make it work?

Comment: Might be a slow network connection, do videos play as expected when not in the VM?

Comment: You don't say which VM, but virtualbox does have extra goodies(not sure of name)download to have it work better, Think VMware has similar.

Comment: @DanielMassey The network is fine and YouTube works everwhere else